# how can I pass variables from one class to another?

Tags: python, class, variables, inheritance, composition

I updated this question. I'm creating two windows and trying to pass variables that created in class A to class B. Could you please point out what's the problem in my code please? Here is my method:

```
class Welcome:

       def __init__(self, master, csv_name_sub, csv_name_ses):
            self.entrySes = Entry(self.master, bg="LemonChiffon3")  
            self.entrySub=Entry(self.master,bg="LemonChiffon3")
            self.csv_name_sub = str(self.entrySub.get())
            self.csv_name_ses = str(self.entrySes.get())
            #here users enter some info, they are saved to be used as file name the in following class

class App(Welcome):
       def __init__(self, master):
            Welcome.__init__(self, master, csv_name_ses, csv_name_sub)  #I'm trying use this line to pass the variables from the first class 
            print('session is', self.csv_name_ses)
            print("subject is", self.csv_name_sub)
            self.resultFile = open(
            "C:\\Users\\xxx" + self.csv_name_sub + '_' + self.csv_name_ses +
        '_results.csv', 'w')
       #.....
       #other codes

def main():

    root = Tk()
    myApp = Welcome(root, csv_name_ses, csv_name_sub)
    root.mainloop()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

The program can be run, but the variables `csv_name_ses` and `csv_name_sub` are not passed to `class App`, as they are not printed out in the class.

I have also tried the method of Composition as below, still can't solve the problem:

```
class Welcome:
    def __init__(self, master, csv_name_sub, csv_name_ses):
            self.entrySes = Entry(self.master, bg="LemonChiffon3")  
            self.entrySub=Entry(self.master,bg="LemonChiffon3")
            self.csv_name_sub = str(self.entrySub.get())
            self.csv_name_ses = str(self.entrySes.get())

class App:
    def __init__(self, master, csv_name_ses, csv_name_sub):
           self.csv_name_sub = csv_name_sub
           self.csv_name_ses = csv_name_ses
           self.welcomePage = Welcome(master, csv_name_ses, csv_name_sub)
           print('session is', self.welcomePage.csv_name_ses)
           print("subject is", self.welcomePage.csv_name_sub)
    self.resultFile = open(
        "C:\\Users\\xxx + self.welcomePage.csv_name_sub + '_' + self.welcomePage.csv_name_ses +
        '_resultsofPart.csv', 'w')
```

Comment: Accept them as arguments (there are several methods) and call the base class. You'll also want to create an instance 'App' *which is a subclass of* 'Welcome' - there is only one *instance* created in a subclass scenario and it is confusing to think of "passed to class". Or perhaps it is more appropriate for Welcome to be a subclass of App? Or maybe it would be simpler and less confusing to use Composition?

Comment: Thanks for your comment and suggestion. I tried to use Composition, but still can't use the variables in the subclass. I have updated in the question, would you mind look at it for me please? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the use of `super class`, to inherit var and values from the parent class, the child class need to refer to the parent class, such that `Welcome.csv_name_ses`.

```
class Welcome:

   def __init__(self, master, csv_name_sub, csv_name_ses):
        self.entrySes = Entry(self.master, bg="LemonChiffon3")  
        self.entrySub=Entry(self.master,bg="LemonChiffon3")
        writeToFile()

   def writeToFile(self):
        Welcome.csv_name_sub = str(self.entrySub.get())
        Welcome.csv_name_ses = str(self.entrySes.get())


class App(Welcome):
   def __init__(self, master, csv_name_ses, csv_name_sub):
        Welcome.__init__(self, master, csv_name_ses, csv_name_sub)
        self.csv_name_sub = Welcome.csv_name_sub
        self.csv_name_ses = Welcome.csv_name_ses  #parent.var

def main():

   root = Tk()
   myApp = Welcome(root, csv_name_ses, csv_name_sub)
   root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1):

Use default arguments and `or` to init the `self` fields:

```
class Welcome:

    def __init__(self, master, csv_name_sub=None, csv_name_ses=None):
        self.entrySes = Entry(self.master, bg="LemonChiffon3")  
        self.entrySub=Entry(self.master,bg="LemonChiffon3")
        self.csv_name_sub = csv_name_sub or str(self.entrySub.get())
        self.csv_name_ses = csv_name_ses or str(self.entrySes.get())
```

Comment: Thanks for you suggestion. I have tried to use `csv_name_sub = None`, `csv_name_ses = None`, but the variables can't still pass from `class Welcome` to `class App`. Do you have more detailed explanation why I should add `None` here? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that Welcome class needs 3 args to be instanciated, and you're only giving one which is "root".

Comment: Thanks, I added other two variables and the program can be run now. But `csv_name_sub` and `csv_name_ses` still not pass to the second class, as the values can't be printed in the the second class. Do you know what is the error in terms of this passing variables problem? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Since the constructor function of the `Welcome` class is `__init__(self, master, csv_name_sub, csv_name_ses)`, you need to provide a value for `csv_name_sub` and `csv_name_ses` as well to instantiate this class. Since you are not actually using the passed values of `csv_name_sub` and `csv_name_ses` (see the first 4 lines in the `__init__` function of your `Welcome` class), this might be a solution that works:

```
class Welcome:

   def __init__(self, master):
        self.entrySes = Entry(self.master, bg="LemonChiffon3")  
        self.entrySub=Entry(self.master,bg="LemonChiffon3")
        self.csv_name_sub = str(self.entrySub.get())
        self.csv_name_ses = str(self.entrySes.get())
        #here users enter some info, they are saved to be used as file name the in following class

class App(Welcome):
   def __init__(self, master):
        Welcome.__init__(self, master) 
        print('session is', self.csv_name_ses)
        print("subject is", self.csv_name_sub)
        self.resultFile = open(
        "C:\\Users\\xxx" + self.csv_name_sub + '_' + self.csv_name_ses +
    '_results.csv', 'w')
   #.....
   #other codes
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But it doesn't pass the variables in `class App`. And I don't really understand what you mean by the passes values are not actually used as I only use them in naming of my document. Is that different from other types of use?